# Safely remove children in a tag by beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Assume that now I have a tag `div` obtained by findAll in a soup.

```
div = <div>text1<span>text2<\span>text3</div>
```

Notice that there are the external structures that I want to keep. For example, `div.previous_element` will connect to other tags in the soup. Now I unwarped span so that

`div.contents=['text1','text2','text3']`

What I want is:

1. div.contents=['text1text2text3']
2. div.string is not none.
3. connection to soup is not cut (div.previous_element also working)

Comment: Could you please provide, how the desired output should look like.

Comment: I expect div=<div>text1text2text3</div>. Also, div.string='text1text2text3' (not none).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html='''<div>text1<span>text2<\span>text3</div>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
div = doc.div
print (div)
print (div.text)
```

Result:

```
{'tag': 'div', 'html': 'text1<span>text2<\\span>text3'}
text1text2text3
```

You can get the examples of SimplifiedDoc [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)